# Check background colour of the grid of buttons in my code

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to do, is get it so when all of the buttons have been turned to black, it displays the h2 text in the 'lightsoff' div. So if any of the buttons aren't black, the text will be hidden.

I'd like to be able to do it by writing a new function that carries out the checking of the background colour.

```js
function toggle(i, j) {
  b = document.getElementById("but_" + i + j)
  t = b.innerHTML
  if (t == "X") {
    b.innerHTML = "O";
    b.setAttribute("style", "color:red; background-color:yellow")
  }
  if (t == "O") {
    b.innerHTML = "X";
    b.setAttribute("style", "color:white; background-color:black")
  }
}

function press(i, j) {
  toggle(i, j);

  if (i > 0) {
    toggle(i - 1, j);
  }
  if (i < 4) {
    toggle(i + 1, j);
  }
  if (j > 0) {
    toggle(i, j - 1);
  }
  if (j < 4) {
    toggle(i, j + 1);
  }
}

function generateGrid() {
  var d = document.getElementById("button-grid");
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  d.appendChild(table);
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.innerHTML = "<button type=button id=but_" + i + j +
        " onclick=\"press(" + i + ',' + j + ")\"" +
        " style=\"color:red; background-color:yellow\"" +
        ">O</button>";
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
  toggle(2, 2)
}

window.onload = function() {
  generateGrid();
};
```

```html
<center>

  <h1>Lights Off Puzzle</h1>

  <h3>Click on the buttons until they all turn black!</h3>

  <div id="button-grid"></div>

  <div id="lightsoff">
    <h2>All the lights are out, you win!</h2>
  </div>

</center>
```

Comment: classes are so much easier to work with. So easy just to query a class and see if it matches the size.

Comment: so what do you suggest I change?

Comment: toggle a class on, active, off, etc instead of seeing the color directly

Comment: sorry I'm really new to javascript, would you be able to tell me how to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1):

Use classes and count

```js
function toggle(i, j) {
  b = document.getElementById("but_" + i + j)
  t = b.innerHTML
  if (t == "X") {
    b.innerHTML = "O";
    b.className="on"
  }
  if (t == "O") {
    b.innerHTML = "X";
    b.className="off"
  }
  var off = document.querySelectorAll(".off").length === document.querySelectorAll("#button-grid table tr td").length; // are all off
  document.getElementById("lightsoff").style.display= off ? "block":"none"; // ternary shorthand for if (something) x=a; else x=b;
}

function press(i, j) {
  toggle(i, j);

  if (i > 0) {
    toggle(i - 1, j);
  }
  if (i < 4) {
    toggle(i + 1, j);
  }
  if (j > 0) {
    toggle(i, j - 1);
  }
  if (j < 4) {
    toggle(i, j + 1);
  }
}

function generateGrid() {
  var d = document.getElementById("button-grid");
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  d.appendChild(table);
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.innerHTML = "<button type=button id=but_" + i + j +
        " onclick=\"press(" + i + ',' + j + ")\"" +
        " class='red'" +
        ">O</button>";
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
  toggle(2, 2)
}

window.onload = function() {
  generateGrid();
};
```

```css
.on {color:red; background-color:yellow} 
.off {color:white; background-color:black}
#lightsoff { display: none }
```

```html
<center>

  <h1>Lights Off Puzzle</h1>

  <h3>Click on the buttons until they all turn black!</h3>

  <div id="button-grid"></div>

  <div id="lightsoff">
    <h2>All the lights are out, you win!</h2>
  </div>

</center>
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do it without changing any of my javascript code, or at least changing very little, and by creating a new function that handles the checking of the background colour and then the displaying of the text.

Comment: So I streamlined your code and gave a one liner - why is that an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Toggle a class using `classList` for the state and then look at the number of elements with that class by using `querySelectorAll()`.

```js
function toggle(i, j) {
  b = document.getElementById("but_" + i + j)
  b.classList.toggle("on")
  b.textContent = b.classList.contains("on") ? "O" : "X"
}

function press(i, j) {
  toggle(i, j);

  if (i > 0) {
    toggle(i - 1, j);
  }
  if (i < 4) {
    toggle(i + 1, j);
  }
  if (j > 0) {
    toggle(i, j - 1);
  }
  if (j < 4) {
    toggle(i, j + 1);
  }
  
  console.log("Number of on buttons is: ", document.querySelectorAll("button.on").length)
}

function generateGrid() {
  var d = document.getElementById("button-grid");
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  d.appendChild(table);
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.innerHTML = "<button type=button id=but_" + i + j +
        " onclick=\"press(" + i + ',' + j + ")\"" +
        " class='on' " +
        ">O</button>";
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
  toggle(2, 2)
}

window.onload = function() {
  generateGrid();
};
```

```css
td button{
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #000;
}

td button.on {
  color: red;
  background-color: #FFC;
}
```

```html
<center>

  <h1>Lights Off Puzzle</h1>

  <h3>Click on the buttons until they all turn black!</h3>

  <div id="button-grid"></div>

  <div id="lightsoff">
    <h2>All the lights are out, you win!</h2>
  </div>

</center>
```

If you really want to do it without using classes than you need to loop over all the cells and see if any of them are the color. Checking color codes can be a pain because not all browsers return the same thing. I would just check the text.

```
function check()
  var btns = document.querySelectorAll("button")
  for (var i=0; i<btns.length; i++) {
    if (btns[i].textContent === "O") return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: your 2nd bit of code, function check() is exactly what I'm looking for, would you be able to explain what the return false and return true does?

Comment: um, says false if there is a O and true if there is no O

Comment: sorry if this sounds stupid, Im new to javascript, but where does it say this?

Comment: if it is "0" it returns false.... if not it checks the next element and continues until there is nothing else to check... In that case it is "true" because nothing was "O". Still would be 100% better to be classes...

Comment: Yes I understand this, but how do I know whether the output is true or false? where does it tell me this?

Comment: When you call the function it returns a boolean.... you use that boolean to do what you want to tell the person they solved it or not.....

Comment: You can stick your logic for solved where it says returned true.... does not matter where you do it.

Comment: so how do I use that Boolean to display text?

Comment: `var foo = check(); if (foo) {} else {}`